# How to make apps that depend on communities to grow

Tags: web-applications, social-networking, community-translations

- What do we call an app that depends on its users for information ?
  Example include the Google translate ( or map at a certain extend).
- Imagine for instance I wanted to create an app that help people find the way (or bus stops) in a local scale( quarter), what will I need ?

Any valuable help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This question is off topic on this site.

Comment: I like honesty. So I would have preferred a respond like "sorry I have no idea but you can check *link*.